# Typeset “parsing HTML the Cthulhu way” in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode

There’s [a famous answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1968) in which the user argues that regular expressions cannot be used to parse HTML … while his sanity slowly slips out of his grasp.

Unfortunately, the <del>insane use of Unicode combining characters</del> influence of the unholy child means that no browser can really render the text correctly. At any rate, it looks *something* like this (excerpt):

[image: unholy screenshot]

I tried rendering the poem in XeLaTeX (mostly to try out to what extent that would work). But to my huge disappointment, the compilation fails right from the outset. How would I go about compiling such a document in XeLaTeX? What do I have to pay special attention to? My attempts yield this error when running `xelatex file`:

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: CID count > 65535
>
> Output file removed.
>   (see the transcript file for additional information)
>   Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;

And no output file is produced.

Here’s minimal document to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\st#1{#1}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}

\begin{document}
You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex
is beautiful t​he f\texttt{inal snuf}fing o\emph{f the lie​\textbf{s
of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T A}}\textbf{LL I​S L}OST th\emph{e pon̷y he come}s he
c̶̮om\st{es he co}\textbf{\st{me}s t\emph{he} ich​}or permeat\emph{es al}l MY
FAC\emph{E MY FACE ᵒh god n\textbf{o NO NOO̼}}\textbf{O​O N}Θ stop t\emph{he
an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨ}e̠̅s\texttt{ ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e} n\textbf{​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ T}O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳
TH̘\textbf{Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝}S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ
\end{document}
```

I’ve chosen fonts that have many Unicode characters defined. There are probably better choices, though. Here’s [the complete document as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/ded72ba702466eb5fd58).

Is there *any chance* with current technology to (a) compile the document and (b) make it render *correctly* (i.e. as intended by the Unicode standard)? Is it necessary (or even *possible*) to replace the Unicode diacritics with LaTeX commands to render them correctly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Damn, I hadn’t found that (I did look). At any rate, I’m experiencing a very different error, so the solution there doesn’t work for me. :-( (The document in the other question compiles.)

Comment: Correction, using “Doulos SIL” fixes the compiler error. It doesn’t fix the rest of the problems, of course (in accordance with the other question). So yeah, looks like an (unsolved) duplicate.

Comment: the font error looks like a local problem with the exact font version I guess, as for combining characters really you need to convert them to prefix commands which isn't impossibly difficult probably but any such parsing macros should probably go on the other question.